# Making a 2d ragdoll in unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am trying to make a ragdoll player in unity 2d. All the parts of the character are held together by hinges and I'm trying to make it move. I do not want to use animations as I prefer a real ragdoll. My current movement isn't working, here is my code :)`

```
bool aKey = false;

float speedl = -20f;

private Rigidbody2D rb2D;

private void Start()
{
    rb2D = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    bool aKey = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(aKey == true)
    {
        rb2D.AddForce(transform.forward * speedl);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please look how [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) works .. => **Each frame (=`Update`)** the user holds down the key this returns `true` .. it makes no sense to check this only **once** in `Start`

Answer (score 2):

Start function run only once so move your GetKey functions to inside of Update() function.

```
private void Start()
{
  rb2D = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}


void Update()
{
  if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
  {
    rb2D.AddForce(transform.forward * speedl);
  }
}
```